# Re-upload app which is in "Waiting for upload" status

Tags: iphone

I have uploaded iphone app in iTunes Connect and the status is "Waiting for upload" from past 7 days. I dont see the "Binary details" option under "Links". Now how do i re-upload the app? or should i re-upload or still wait for some more days? Please suggest.

i have uploaded the app through xcode and the status says "Passed Validation". Now do i need to create ipa and upload it through Application loader again?

Thanks.

Comment: You should contact Apple directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you have successfully uploaded your app. Try to upload it again.

If your upload is successful, it should be changed to *Upload Received* and then shortly it should be changed to *Waiting For Review*.

Take a look at [iTunes Connect Developer Guide: Managing Your Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/10_ManagingYourApplications/ManagingYourApplications.html) for the list of possible status. And if your app status is still *waiting for upload*, it means:

> Appears when you’ve completed entering your metadata and indicated
>   that you are ready to submit your binary, however, you have not
>   finished uploading your binary through Application Loader. Your app
>   must be Waiting For Upload for you to be able to deliver your binary
>   through Application Loader.

Comment: i have uploaded the app through xcode and the status says "Passed Validation". Now do i need to create ipa and upload it through Application loader again?

Comment: @Arun Wait, it just passed the validation. You have not uploaded it. Now press the "Distribute" button below the "Validate" button to submit it to the App Store.